# Counterexample to "$A \to B, A \to C$, therefore $B \to C$"

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, propositional-calculus

We have $A\to B$ and $A\to C$. I need counter-examples to: '$\therefore B\to C$'.

More formally, disprove:

$$ (A\to B)\land(A\to C)\to (B\to C)$$

I have $A$ is a blackbird, $B$ is 'is black', $C$ is 'is a bird', and so $B \not\to C$. Does anyone have a more numerical solution?

(alternatively, cases where this is true...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathcal A & = \{5,6\} \\
\mathcal B & = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \\
\mathcal C & = \{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\} \\[12pt]
A & = [x\in\mathcal A] \\
B & = [x\in\mathcal B] \\
C & = [x\in\mathcal C]
\end{align}

Then $A\to B$ and $A\to C$ are true but $B\to C$ is false.

Second example:
\begin{align}
A & = [x\in\{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}] \\
B & = [x \text{ is rational}] \\
C & = [x>0]
\end{align}

Comment: and $A\subset B\subset C$ is a case when it's true.

Answer (score 4):

$$x = -1 \implies x^4 = 1$$
$$x = -1 \implies x^3 = -1$$

But

$$x^4 = 1\not\Rightarrow x^3 = -1$$

because $x^3$ could be equals to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

$A$: "I do not exist"
$B$: "I work for a living"
$C$: "I am a billionaire"

In other words, make $A$ false, $B$ true, $C$ false.

Answer (score 0):

Oh.  You wanted *numerical* examples.

The number 2 is even, 2 is prime, therefore all even numbers are prime.

3 is a square root, 3 is rational.  All square roots are rational.

*Ooh* here's a good one:

$20|x \implies 5|x$

$20|x \implies 4|x$

Ergo $5|x \implies 4|x$.

Etc. etc.

=====old answer ===

A: is a fish

B: lives in water

C: has gills.

Therefore sea otters have gills

=====

A: is ice cream

B: starts with the letter I

C: is made from milk

Therefore Insects are made out of milk.

=====

The possibilities are *endless*.